# Getting Incompitable Types with the Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create Navigation drawer in Android Studio. 
My code is as follows:

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mList;
private ArrayList<com.zaptech.webdata.model.MenuItem> listMenu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
    findViews();
    Toolbar mTool = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mTool);
    getSupportActionBar(). setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    //noinspection deprecation
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(NavigationActivity.this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    //mList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(NavigationActivity.this,));

    //mList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
            Snackbar.make(view, "Developed By Bandish", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_navigation, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void findViews() {
    mDrawerToggle = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
}
```

When I import the following:

**import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle; 
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;**

I get the these errors:

```
Required import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout; 
Found import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Thanks!

Comment: try removing `import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;`

Comment: I have already tried it. But, Same Error showing inside findViews() function for the mDrawerToggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend you have declared

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerToggle;
```

Instead you should use `ActionBarDrawerToggle`

and your reference to drawerlayout is wrong

```
private void findViews() {
     mDrawerToggle = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

it should be

```
 mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

Comment: Sorry, I have already declared mDrawerToggle as ActionBarDrawerToggle. Recently, I have changed my code. Please, check it.

Comment: you have not changed  mDrawerToggle = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); it should be mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);